# PHP/JS content swap is echoing a "1" after everything? Can't find source

Tags: javascript, php

I have a basic content swapper using JS and PHP. Everything was working fine until I noticed the script was echoing a number "1" after placing the results of the swap. There was no number one in my html, php includes, or scripts (that I could find.) Where the hell is it coming from and how can I get it to not appear.

JS

```
function swapContent(cv){
    $("#workwrap").html(loadgif.gif).show();
    var url = "includescripts/swapscript.php";
    $.post(url,{contentVar:cv},function(data){
        $("#workwrap").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
    $contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];
    if($contentVar == "logo"){
        echo include("../workincludes/contA.php");
    } else if($contentVar == "print"){
        echo include("../workincludes/contB.php");
    } else if($contentVar == "web"){
        echo include("../workincludes/contC.php");
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<div id="workwrap">
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `echo` before `include` `call`, `include` returns 1 on success

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to `echo` the include.
The '1's are the status `true` (parsed as string) from successfully including the files.

For future if you get Ones or Zeores in the result, check if you tried to echo the result of a function.

[include manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

`Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1`